# How to keep session informations using curl in php?

Tags: php, curl

Access to fictitious page `www.randomDomain.com/onlyForRegisteredUsers` is possible only when I will log in first. So
I did this:

```
...
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->currentUseragent;
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->currentIP);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->currentUrl); //www.randomDomain.com/login/
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->currentData);
    //with login RandomUserName and pass *******
$page = curl_exec($this->curl);
```

And successfully in $page I have got result something like this: `...<p>Welcome back, RandomUserName!</p>`.

How to keep informations about session that I am already logged in, and then read content from `www.randomDomain.com/onlyForRegisteredUsers` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$cookieFile = 'cookie.txt';
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($cookieFile));
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath($cookieFile));
```

Note : the cookie file must exist, you can create the file if not exist with :

```
if (!file_exists(realpath($cookieFile)))
{
    touch($cookieFile);
}
```